# In Django 2.0 How do I handle a ProtectedError in generic.DeleteView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a generic view declared as follows:

```
class CustomerDelete(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):

    model = models.Customer
    success_url = reverse_lazy('customer-list')
```

And a model declared as follows:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    Customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=None)
    Shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=None)
    Status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS);
    Reference = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    LastAuthorizationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    LastUpdated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('order-view', None, [self.id])    

    def type(self):
        return 'Order'

    def Name(self):
        return self.Customer.Name + ' - ' + self.Shop.Name + ' - ' + self.Reference
```

Upon delete I get the following exception:

> ProtectedError at /customer/2/delete/ ("Cannot delete some instances
>   of model 'Customer' because they are referenced through a protected
>   foreign key: 'Order.Customer'", ,
>   , , , ]>)

What would be the best class method to override and catch the exception that would allow me to redirect to the referrer with an error attached?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the `delete` method, to add your custom logic:

```
class CustomerDelete(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):

    model = models.Customer
    success_url = reverse_lazy('customer-list')
    error_url = reverse_lazy('customer-has-orders-error')

    def get_error_url(self):
        if self.error_url:
            return self.error_url.format(**self.object.__dict__)
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
               "No error URL to redirect to. Provide a error_url.")

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            """
            Call the delete() method on the fetched object and then redirect. 
            """
           self.object = self.get_object()
           success_url = self.get_success_url()
           error_url = self.get_error_url()
           try:
                self.object.delete()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
           except models.ProtectedError:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(error_url)
```

If you are going to be using this often, you can create your own custom mixin with the above logic.

In addition, consider implementing a soft delete in your application, so that records are not deleted from the database immediately, but are flagged for deletion at a later date - once they are archived. Otherwise you risk having issues with your business logic.

Comment: I am getting this error: `Reverse for 'customer-has-orders-error' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ...` . In my view I have used the URL for the DeleteView. What could I be doing wrong?